# how to reshape an matrix to a shape equal to a given matrix, given bothe arrays have same number of elements using numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

NumPy m1 = [[25, 56, 12],[ 85, 34, 75]]

Create a new matrix m2 with the shape equal to m1 filled with ones.

Comment: You may have a look at `numpy.ones_like()`

Comment: If `m1` is a numpy array, then you can create a new matrix with the same shape like this `m2 = np.ones(m1.shape)`

Answer (score 1):

Just use [numpy.ones](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ones.html)

```
import numpy as np

m1 = np.array([[25, 56, 12],[ 85, 34, 75]])
m2 = np.ones(m1.shape)
```